# Как передать число из datepicker jQuery в переменную php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Используя вот [эти формы](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php) отправить данные методом POST в переменную php ?

Comment: Там совершенно обычный тег `input`. Поэтому работайте с ними как с совершенно обычной HTML формой с POST запросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input id='dataTime' size="16" type="text" value="2012-06-15 14:45" readonly class="form_datetime">
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'datatime.php',
            data: { dataTime: $("#dataTime").val()},
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json'
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res.mess)
            }
        })
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['dataTime'])) {
    $dataTime = $_POST['dataTime'];
   return  json_encode(['type'=> 'success', 'mess' => 'Ok']);
} else {
    return  json_encode(['type'=> 'error', 'mess' => 'Not found']);
}
```